# How to put an auto-play video as a background in the section of a webpage( as here - http://www8.hp.com/in/en/home.html)?

Tags: javascript, css, html, web-deployment

The [HP-India website](http://www8.hp.com/in/en/home.html) has an autoplay video in the background of a section below the header. How can I recreate something similar?

Comment: Look at the source code?

Comment: I guess the source code reveal him only the html specific part of the browser using no way to do it responsive adaptative to some major part of devices.

Comment: What I always do when I try to recreate an effect on a web-page is copy the source code into a text editor and remove things that I think are related to it.  If the effect doesn't appear on the web-page anymore I know that bit of code has something to do with it.

Comment: I Guess copy/paste if is for speed dev and no real matter to do it. But a minimum of knowing what you do with it and what you want to serve as device you need a little more than a simple copy paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use media queries for responsive way, i didn't use any code of this site just the source video webm and mp4. I did my own skill in CSS, may be you can make it more efficient but i am no designer ...

```css
div.content, div.top, div.footer{
 float:left;
 position: relative;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 z-index:1000;
 width:100%;
 border-radius:2px;
}
.top{
 background-color:red;
 margin-bottom:20px;
}
.content{
 background-color:green;
 min-height:600px;
 height:60%;
 opacity:0.5;
}
.footer{
background-color:yellow;
}
@meia all and (max-width: 1080px) {
 .video-background video{ left:-600px;}
}

@media all and (max-width: 980px) {
 .video-background video{ left:-300px;}
}

@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
 .video-background video{ left:-300px;}
}

@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
 .video-background video{ left:-300px;}
}

@media all and (max-width: 750px) {
 .video-background video{ left:-380px;}
}

@media all and (max-width: 640px) {
 .video-background video{ left:-280px;}
}

@media all and (max-width: 360px) {
 .video-background video{ left:-180px;}
}

@media all and (max-width: 320px) {
 .video-background video{ left:-160px;}
 }
.video-background video{position: fixed;top:0px;min-width: 100%;min-height: 100%;}
.video-background{min-width:100%;min-height:100%;height:100%;width:100%;position:fixed;top:0px;}
```

```html
<div class="top">HEADER</div>
<div class="video-background">
<video controls="" controlslist="nodownload" style="position:fixed;z-index:-1;" poster="http://www.remmache.fr/sites/default/files/background_video/douceur.jpg" autoplay="" loop="" muted="" playsinline=""><source src="http://storage.media.ext.hp.com/sprocket/sprocket_oct.webm" type="video/webm" onerror="fallback(parentNode)"><source src="http://storage.media.ext.hp.com/sprocket/sprocket_oct.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source src="http://www.remmache.fr/sites/default/files/background_video/Coloring.ogv" type="video/ogg"></video></div>
<div class="content">i am the content .... </div>
<div class="footer">footer</div>
```